# How do I get $index from an ng-repeat table to a modal controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a table of customer records created with angularjs bootstrap-ui and uses ng-repeat.

At the end of each line in the table is a button to get more information about the customer.

When the button is clicked a modal form pops with the information.

my problem is whichever button I press I get the same customer number

The problem is I need to get the value of $index to the following bit of code:

```
$scope.selected = {
    customer: $scope.customers[0]
};
```

The value of $index needs to replace the 0 value above

What I have done so far can be seen on plunker click [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DNHT1ekB12rlC9KSGzUU?p=info)

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
  < div class = "modal-header" > < h3 > I am a modal! < /h3>
    </div > < div class = "modal-body" > < form class = "form-horizontal"
  role = "form" > < div class = "form-group" > < label
  for = "customerNumber"
  class = "col-lg-2 control-label" > Email Address: < /label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customerNumber" 
                        ng-model="selected.customer.customerNumber"
                        ng-value="selected.customer.customerNumber">
            </div > < /div>
        </form > < /div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button > < button class = "btn btn-warning"
  ng - click = "cancel()" > Cancel < /button>
    </div >
</script>
<div>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Customer number</th>
        <th>Customer name</th>
        <th>Customer last name</th>
        <th>Customer first name</th>
        <th>phone</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="customer in customers">
      <tr>
        <td>{{ customer.customerNumber }}</td>
        <td>{{ customer.customerName }}</td>
        <td>{{ customer.contactLastName }}</td>
        <td>{{ customer.contactFirstName }}</td>
        <td>{{ customer.phone }}</td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">
            Customer details
          </button>
        </td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>


'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {


$scope.customers = [
    {
        "customerNumber": 103,
        "customerName": "Atelier graphique",
        "contactLastName": "Schmitt",
        "contactFirstName": "Carine ",
        "phone": "40.32.2555"

    },
    {
        "customerNumber": 112,
        "customerName": "Signal Gift Stores",
        "contactLastName": "King",
        "contactFirstName": "Jean",
        "phone": "7025551838"

    },
    {
        "customerNumber": 114,
        "customerName": "Australian Collectors, Co",
        "contactLastName": "Ferguson",
        "contactFirstName": "Peter",
        "phone": "03 9520 4555"
    }
];

$scope.open = function () {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
        resolve: {
            customers: function () {
                return $scope.customers
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedCustomer) {
        $scope.selected = selectedCustomer;
    }, function () {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
};
});

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, customers) {

$scope.customers = customers;
$scope.selected = {
    customer: $scope.customers[0]
};

$scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.customer);
};

$scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
}
}
```

Answer (score 10):

ng-repeat directive has a variable

```
$index
```

You can pass this variable in the click function like this

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($index)">
    Customer details
</button>
```

You need to accept this index as a parameter in your method, so just add the parameter

```
$scope.open = function (index) {
  .... your method body
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Pass the customer object to your function first:

```
ng-click="ok(customer)"
```

Then find the index based on that object in your function:

```
$scope.ok = function (customer) {
  var index = $scope.customers.indexOf(customer);
  $scope.selected.customer = $scope.customers[index];
  $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.customer);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't do it like this - instead work with actual customer objects. Correct me if I am wrong but it looks like you have some kind of list of customers that when you click on them opens a modal with more details. Try something like this:

In the customer table:

```
    <tbody ng-repeat="customer in customers">
      <tr>
        <td>{{ customer.customerNumber }}</td>
        <td>{{ customer.customerName }}</td>
        <td>{{ customer.contactLastName }}</td>
        <td>{{ customer.contactFirstName }}</td>
        <td>{{ customer.phone }}</td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open(customer)">
            Customer details
          </button>
        </td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.open = function(customer){

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
        resolve: {
            customer: function () {
                return customer;
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedCustomer) {
        $scope.selected = selectedCustomer;
    }, function () {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });

};
```

And in the modal controller:

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, customer) {

$scope.customer = customer;

$scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.customer);
};

$scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
}
}
```

And finally, in the modal view:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
  < div class = "modal-header" > < h3 > I am a modal! < /h3>
    </div > < div class = "modal-body" > < form class = "form-horizontal"
  role = "form" > < div class = "form-group" > < label
  for = "customerNumber"
  class = "col-lg-2 control-label" > Email Address: < /label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customerNumber" 
                        ng-model="customer.customerNumber"
                        ng-value="customer.customerNumber">
            </div > < /div>
        </form > < /div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button > < button class = "btn btn-warning"
  ng - click = "cancel()" > Cancel < /button>
    </div >
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions Rob and Fourth.

I used a combination of both your suggestions

You can see the result on plunker by clicking [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/peo1gTBNlJAmCUoSUiD7?p=info)

The changes are shown below

```
<td>
    <button class="btn btn-default" 
        ng-click="open(customer)"> <!-- Customer object now goes to controller-->
        Customer details
    </button>
</td>
```

Inside the controller the customer object is in scope of the open function only.

I had to get index so I could use it with the customers object

```
resolve: {
    customerIndex: function () {
        return $scope.customers.indexOf(customer)
    },
    customers: function () {
        return $scope.customers
    }
}
```

Both customers and customerIndex are used in the ModalInstanceCtrl

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, customers, customerIndex) {

$scope.customers = customers;
$scope.selected = {
    customer: $scope.customers[customerIndex]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be even simpler if you directly use `$index`. Hence, you will not require to lookup for the index using the customer object in your controller. Please have a look at the following it could also be tested on, [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/GcxCAW38GJ0232tLJTGZ?p=preview)

### **index.html**

```
<td>
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($index)">
    Customer details
  </button>
</td>
```

### **example.js**

```
  // code above this controller method wasn't modified
  $scope.open = function (index) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
        resolve: {
            index: function() {
                return index;
            },
            customers: function () {
                return $scope.customers
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedCustomer) {
        $scope.selected = selectedCustomer;
    }, function () {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
});

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, customers, index) {
  $scope.customers = customers;
  $scope.selected = {
    customer: $scope.customers[index]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.customer);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  }
}
```