# Selecting parent row unless child rows exist in Angular Table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table that displays selectable information. Sometimes there are child rows that are selectable.

I want the parent rows to be selectable if they have no children, otherwise only the child rows should be selectable. This is a select-only-one type of table.

Right now the parent rows are selectable, but when the row with the child rows is selected, everything is selected. I am using nested ng-repeats so this complicates matters.

Here is a plunker.

http://plnkr.co/edit/baCIxeJB5JeVAJU8O7Hy?p=preview

The select isn't working in the plunker but it is on my machine... I'm running Angular 1.4.7 and ui_bootstrap 1.1.2. However I think it is enough to see what is going on.

Here is the markup:

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S</th>
            <th>R</th>
            <th>Se</th>
            <th>D</th>
            <th>Ser</th>
            <th>L</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody ng-repeat="x in pro" ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}" ng-click="setClickedRow($index)">
        <tr >
            <td><b>{{x.a}}</b></td>
            <td>{{x.b}}</td>
            <td><u>{{x.c}}</u></td>
            <td>{{x.d}}</td>
            <td>{{x.e}}</td>
            <td>{{x.f}}</td>

            <tr ng-repeat = "details in x.jobs">
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>{{details.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{details.jobs}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is the controller

```
$scope.setClickedRow = function(index){
  $scope.selectedRow = ($scope.selectedRow == index) ? null : index;
};

    $scope.pro = [
      {
        a : "G",
        b : "123",
        c : "S1",
        d : "D6",
        e : "O1",
        f : "B",
        jobs : [
          {
            "name": "Wakeup",

          },
          {
            "name": "work 9-5",

          }
        ]
      },
         {
        a : "R",
        b : "456",
        c : "S2",
        d : "D5",
        e : "O2",
        f : "B",
        jobs : [
        ]
      },
         {
        a : "G",
        b : "789",
        c : "S3",
        d : "D4",
        e : "O3",
        f : "P",
        jobs : [
          {
            "name": "Sleep",

          },
          {
            "name": "get ready for bed",

          }
        ]
         },
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tbody**

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="(pIndex, x) in pro" ng-class="{'selected': parentSelected[$index]}" ng-click="setParentClickedRow(x, $index)">
    <td>
      <b>{{x.a}}</b>
    </td>
    <td>{{x.b}}</td>
    <td>
      <u>{{x.c}}</u>
    </td>
    <td>{{x.d}}</td>
    <td>{{x.e}}</td>
    <td>{{x.f}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="details in x.jobs" ng-class="{'selected': childSelected[pIndex][$index]}" ng-click="setChildClickedRow(pIndex, $index)">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{details.name}}</td>
        <td>{{details.jobs}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**controller snippet**

```
$scope.parentSelected = [];
$scope.childSelected = [];

$scope.setParentClickedRow = function(x, index) {
  if(!x.jobs || x.jobs.length === 0) {
    $scope.parentSelected[index] = !$scope.parentSelected[index];
  } 
};

$scope.setChildClickedRow = function(parentIndex, index) {
  $scope.childSelected[parentIndex] = $scope.childSelected[parentIndex] || [];
  $scope.childSelected[parentIndex][index] = !$scope.childSelected[parentIndex][index];
}
```

Previously, your `tbody` element was applied class `selected`. It was a mistake. Also, there was no attempt for checking/distinguishing between a parent row and child rows.

I replaced the `ng-repeat` with `ng-repeat-start` and started iterating the `tr`. It has nothing to do with the logic, it's just that I did't want to do iteration with `tbody` and generate `tbody` for each iteration.

The logic is in setParentClickedRow and setChildClickedRow function. In setParentClickedRow function, check if that parent object has child obj(length > 0) that created child rows. If not, we make it selectable by changing `parentSelected` array. In `setChildClickedRow` function, we just change `childSelected` (two dimensional array) to make a child row selectable.

See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NCaa9Q17GgKCs3LOmALV?p=preview).

Comment: This mostly works, and your explanation is good. How can I make it select only one? I don't want multi-select.

Comment: @jenryb Whether it is parent or child rows, you want only one row selected at a time in the whole table. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Ultimately what I am going for is when you click on a row, it returns the data of that row. I am trying to do it using this stackoverflow as an example but get caught up with the indices of childrows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24888816/how-do-i-get-index-from-an-ng-repeat-table-to-a-modal-controller

Comment: What happens when you select a parent row or it's child row? You show the same data for both parent and it's child?

Comment: Good question. Yes, you show the data for both parent and the child row selected. Or just the parent if there is no child row.

Comment: Please, see this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TdWPbW4JeLOVFT1zwwjE?p=preview). When you select a parent row(that is with no child), you will get the parent object in the `ng-click` function. When you select a child row, you will get both parent object and child object in the `ng-click` function. Using the parent obj or parent + child obj, you can get the details accordingly. Let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Any chance you know how to add a hover component so it only hovers on the rows that are selectable? If so, answer here so I can accept your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448543/disable-table-hover-on-certain-row-in-angular-bootstrap

Comment: @jenryb ok, let me see the post.