# Disable table-hover on certain row in Angular Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table that displays selectable information. Sometimes there are child rows that are selectable.

I want the parent rows to be selectable if they have no children, otherwise only the child rows should be selectable. This is a select-only-one type of table.

This table works as expected. However, I want to disable the hover on the non-selectable parent row.

Here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Z0cgHKx2qxpekEE36O1K?p=preview

Here is an example of some of the code in the controller:

```
    scope.parentSelected = [];
$scope.childSelected = [];

$scope.getParentDetails = function(parentObj) {
  if(!parentObj.jobs || parentObj.jobs.length === 0) {
    nonSelectOtherRows(); 
    var index = $scope.pro.indexOf(parentObj);
    $scope.parentSelected[index] = !$scope.parentSelected[index];

    // get details for parent row using parentObj
    console.log(parentObj);
  } 
};

$scope.getChildDetails = function(parentObj, childObj) {
  nonSelectOtherRows();
  var parentIndex = $scope.pro.indexOf(parentObj);
  var childIndex = parentObj.jobs.indexOf(childObj);
  $scope.childSelected[parentIndex] = [];
  $scope.childSelected[parentIndex][childIndex] = !$scope.childSelected[parentIndex][childIndex];

  // get details for parent and child rows using parentObj and childObj.
  // childObj is the childRow selected
  console.log(parentObj);
  console.log(childObj);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to apply hover class on the selectable child row also or only on the selectable parent row? Also, what happens when you select a selectable parent/child row after hovering upon it? Currently, a `selected` class(yellow background) is applied on the selected parent/child row.

Comment: @Saad I want to apply the hover class on all selectable elements, including the child row and the selectable parent row. Right now what happens when I select a parent/child row when selecting is that it returns data, that functionality works just fine.

Comment: See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1r0JXKjpgU2lmsW1TjiT?p=preview). Let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: @Saad Yes! You rock thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Remove `table-hover` attribute.

Implement your `ng-mouseover` and `ng-mouseleave` functions.

```
$scope.hoverIn = function(row){
   row.hoverEdit = true;//check selectable or not
};
$scope.hoverOut = function(row){
   row.hoverEdit = false;
};
```

Define css class for hover.

```
.custom-hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Finally add class to your `tr`

```
`'custom-hover': x.hoverEdit`
```

here is: http://plnkr.co/edit/CJxi86GyM8jMbtehPQgU?p=preview
Add your selectable control inside hoverIn and it will be work.

Comment: Any chance you could show how the move of the selectable control changes how the hover works? When I try to move my control it breaks the hover

Comment: I don't understand your selectable case. Define a method and check selectable or not. You should just add inside hoverin function : if(IsRowSelectable(row)) row.hoverEdit=true; else row.hoverEdit=false;

Comment: If it helps, if you click on each row, you can see which is selectable and which is not. The parent rows that have stuff underneath aren't selectable.

Answer (score -1):

try to use ng-class. it will help you.